# Concatenate multiple arrays in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to concatenate multiple arrays into one array in Postgres?

For example, something like this:

```
ARRAY_CAT(
    ARRAY_FILL(5, ARRAY[4]),
    ARRAY_FILL(2, ARRAY[3]),
    ARRAY_FILL(11, ARRAY[3])
)
```

For this example, I'd like to see an output of

```
[5,5,5,5,2,2,2,11,11,11]
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the [`||` concatenation operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE)

```
select 
    array_fill(5, array[4]) ||
    array_fill(2, array[3]) ||
    array_fill(11, array[3])
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with repeated concatenations:

```
ARRAY_CAT(
  ARRAY_CAT(
    ARRAY_FILL(5, ARRAY[4]),
    ARRAY_FILL(2, ARRAY[3])
  ),
  ARRAY_FILL(11, ARRAY[3])
)
```

As @Clodoaldo Neto pointed out, you can use the `||` operator too. You can choose freely from these two, but keep in mind:

- `||` can behave differently depending on the operand types. This can cause confusion.
- in the case when both operands are array, `||` is just an alias to `array_cat`. ([source](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/c7b8998ebbf310a156aa38022555a24d98fdbfb4/src/include/catalog/pg_operator.h#L142))